# How a webpage loads in the browser is influenced by the technology of the server

Tags: web-applications

I have noticed that different technologies influence how a web page loads on a screen. That is, the transition from an empty screen (or another webpage) to the webpage that is requested. In fact, I can literally tell which stack is being used just by noticing how the page loads.

- asp.net/iis pages seem to have more of a pause and then load all at once in a spasmodic flash.
- php/apache is very fluid and smooth, seeming to gradually load from the top element down.
- ruby on rails is kind of inbetween the two, there are distinct sections of the page that are loaded at a time, but is fairly smooth.

What influences this? (compiled vs interpreted? when the css is loaded? how the images are loaded?) Can it be controlled in asp.net or iis? Which HTTP concepts is this related to?

Comment: Consider re-phrasing the question, which is currently a statement.

Comment: are you using the same browser for all cases.  I've found IE loads pages slower (all at once before rendering) than others but you can tweak your javascript and css to make it better.

Answer (score 0):

You got yourself some broad, sweeping generalizations, but in general it's true. It's usually not to do with the actual server technology - you can host PHP on IIS, for instance, but with the page generation tools - scripting language and frameworks.

By using tools like Firebug and Yslow, you can see what's going on, and there are many clues in this.

The reason ASP.Net sites behave the way you describe is because of the way they construct the HTML - ASP.Net webforms uses a "form" tag to build the page, and a whole bunch of barely-standards-compliant HTML and JavaScript to glue the page together. The newer ASP.Net MVC technology mostly does away with this, and you should find that sites built using this technology feel smoother. The default ASP.Net page templates don't really follow the YSlow recommendations, so that's why you often see the slight hickup in page load.

PHP sites don't have a single dominant framework - there are at least 4 competing MVC frameworks, as well as numerous homegrown frameworks, as well as "no framework" sites. Some are great, some are not, some are fast, some are slow - it's really hard to generalize.

Finally, Ruby tends to use lots of components to build up the page - each element on the page is likely to have its own model/view/controller part, with its own caching strategy. That means that often, you get a slight delay when a component has to do its thing.